# Story in episodes about an immortal man

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm looking for a short novel from the sixties or seventies about an immortal man. The book is a series of chronological episodes spread over tens of thousands of years,  from ancient to very far future. It deals with how he learns to survive (he can be killed), how he maintains anonymity,
loves mortals, and deals with the loss of mortal friends. Other episodes include encounters with others of his kind.

Comment: This is rather sketchy and thin.  Do you have any more details -- character names, cover description, where it was published (or where you read it, i.e. UK, USA, etc.)?  I have a possible answer in mind, but this could be a lot of things...

Comment: It may or may not have been called the million year man or had the word million in it. I read it twice over the years in the US

Comment: I also remember some pretty specific things about it . He occasionally runs into a violent warrior type, also immortal, survives a nearly mortal Sword cut from him by mearly pinching the wound on his whole upper arm shut an backing away from him

Comment: Thanks Zeiss, could be-- not sure yet tho. Let's see what else comes in

Comment: You may want to withdraw your acceptance until you're sure the answer is correct.  Generally, an accepted answer will tend to discourage other answers (not that I don't want the rep, but you'll get more choices if you wait to accept).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may be Poul Anderson's *Boat of a Million Years*.  It's been so long since I read it, that I remember few details myself, but I do recall it followed unaging humans who had to hide from those who lacked their gift, who eventually met each other (inevitably, as the author wrote it), who dealt with the fact that, after a few thousand years of life, ordinary humans still mattered even though they didn't last.  The very ending had the protagonist making a date with another "immortal" for a million years hence.

Comment: You know Zeiss the more I think about it I think you nailed it

Comment: So I read a couple reviews of Boat of---  on line and that is the book.

Comment: Cool!  Glad I remembered it!